# Python sorting dictionary keys into a list by values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary say:

```
Red : 2
Blue : 1
Yellow : 9
Black : 9
White : 5
```

I need to generate a list of keys sorted by the values:

```
[Blue, Red, White, Black, Yellow]
```

Is there a neatish way of doing this?

I have had a look around, and there are similar questions, but they all seem to be sorting values or keys only.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't consider the question marked "duplicate" to be a duplicate at all. Luckily you got a good answer before that happened.

Comment: Using the duplicate, you get `[('Blue', 1), ('Red', 2), ('White', 5), ('Black', 9)]`. With `[y for y,_ in sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]` you get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function with [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as its key  :

`sorted(your_dictionary.keys(), key=your_dictionary.get)`

or as says in comments you can just use :

`sorted(your_dictionary, key=your_dictionary.get)`

Comment: But this doesnt use the values?

Comment: you can just do `sorted(the_dict,key=the_dict.get)`

Comment: Thanks :) This was surprisingly hard to find.